# IOS - sync events from my app to native calendrer

Tags: ios, react-native

I have an ios app -built with react native- where among other things users can view a calendar of events coming from the API, I want to periodically sync these events to a native calendar as well so even when the user does not use the app it can get reminders of these events.

##### What I've considered:

1- Sync these events every time the user opens that app. which does not meet the complete requirements.

2- Run a background task to get events from the API and sync it to the native calendar. this works on the android side but not on IOS if the app is terminated.

3- Implement CalDav API but my app uses SSO to login and I'm not sure how to make this work with the username/password auth of CalDav.

##### Is there a better way to do this?